# Microsoft Cognitive Services Knowledge Academic Evaluate Response

Tags: json, azure-cognitive-services

```
https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03/console
```

When I enter ~Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')~ value into expr's textbox at the Microsoft Knowledge Academic Evaluate test page (Link Above)

Result has only logprop and id values like that :
    {
      "expr": "Composite(AA.AuN=='jaime teevan')",
      "entities": [
        {
          "logprob": -15.052,
          "Id": 2061503185
        },
        {
          "logprob": -15.373,
          "Id": 2122841972
        }
      ]
    }

Why other properties are not shown? Are there any one faced and fixed this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify which properties you want returned with "attributes="

e.g. append *&attributes=Ti,Y,AA.AuN,E* to your query